# IOS Gif Showing the Last Frame of the Previous Frame

Tags: ios, cordova, gif, animated-gif

I have an cordova ios application where I show a different gif upon swipe up and swipe up.

But when I swipe up the first gif the second gif doesn't start playing properly from it's first frame like it should.

Instead the second gif shows the last frame of the second gif first and then only it starts playing.

Please see the attached gif herewith.

[image]

Because of this it creates an ugly flicker on each image swipe up on the ipad app.

Could someone please point me out what I am doing wrong  or what should I be doing differently to fix this issue ?.

I am tesing using ios 9.1.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an invision prototype. The last frame of the gif always plays first when the gif begins causing an abrupt transition. Would appreciate any ideas here...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a partial answer.

My problem resulted from splitting one rendered image sequence from After Effects into multiple animated gifs in Photoshop.

I think it must have something to do with the way the images are referenced in the image sequence that messes up the final animated gif. Possibly because it loses information about which images are first or last in the process.

I fixed the problem by rendering each image sequence separately then opening each image sequence in Photoshop and saving them as animated gifs separately as well.